# Decrease reputation penalty on negative votes for new users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, down-votes, new-users

Just a thought..

Can we reduce the weight from -2 to -1 for negative votes for users having reputation score less than "20" or "30" (Need an expert opinion on fixing this scale)

**Giving a reason in brief for this proposal:** Reputation is a like an encouragement (In general for everyone and in perticular for Newbies). Mass downvotes just discourage the newbies. I'm not sure how many of you are familiar with that feeling.

A scenario of 20 downvotes lead to loss of 40 points. Having lesser reputation than this user might end up with default 1 score.

Please don't misunderstand me. I'm not against the strict rules but too much strictness sounds too rude sometimes! Making it -1, instead of -2 will have soft impact. All we intend is to make user aware of the rules and regulations. If it can be done in nicer way.. why not?

On Meta, there have been such concerns in past:

- [Negative votes necessary for newbie?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127058/negative-votes-necessary-for-newbie)
- [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But these too nice to appreciate strict rules of this system. Strict rules are mandatory. In my proposal I'm just focusing on impact of points reduction.

Comment: Its a indeed a good request Aravind. I wanted to ask same question and encountered with this question.

Answer (score 12):

I'm against, chiefly for the following reasons:

1. Low reputation users already derive comfort that their reputation can never drop below 1.
2. Negative votes ought to be viewed as an encouragement to improve the question or answer. New users need particular help in this respect in order to fit in to the site's expectations.
3. Reducing the reputation loss could well encourage more slapdash questions and answers.
4. The effect of the "sympathetic vote" phenomenon would worsen: 1 answer upvote would cancel -10 answer downvotes.
5. The development time taken to effect this would be large and reputation would have to be recalculated for all users.

Comment: 2. I don't think negative votes are encouragement to improve questions or answer. A helpful relevant comment 'along with' a negative vote, maybe.

3. There is already a system for handling 'slapdash' questions and answers

Comment: @ouflak: 2. In which case I'm in the minority. I found downvotes very helpful. It often means I've missed the point entirely. 3. That system is vulnerable to being overloaded.

Comment: Downvotes with comments are almost always going to be helpful. Downvotes with no comment might or might not be helpful depending on all sorts of factors that none of us can predict, and for new users, can be discouraging to the point of driving them off the site
rather than 'helping' them.
And it's a bit disappointing to here that the development time would be so cumbersome. Wonder how the system was coded?

Comment: @ouflak Any change to a large system used by hundreds of thousands of people requires development and testing time; it's not a matter of how well it's organized. Besides which, you're neglecting to consider the effect of the change on *current* users. Everyone who had ever gotten a downvote while their rep was lower than the limit would have to have their rep recalculated.