# "Add a comment" link is not grayed for deeply downvoted post

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

When a post has been deeply downvoted, all of its content showed as grayed... except "add a comment" link. [E.g](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127063/339911).:

> [image: gray]

I think this link should looks like another links in the post (in this case to user profiles).

I'm not a web developer so it's hard for me to find a root of the problem, but I pretty sure that showing "add a comment" link with regular color is simply overlook. Perhaps you just need to add the class somewhere in the CSS or something like that.

Any element of the post (except this link) undergo to color changing. Even "share", "edit", and "flag" links. The fact that their color varies insignificantly is not an excuse to say that they do not change at all. I.e. the author's idea assumed that their color should be changed too.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't we encourage comments to help the OP improve the post?

Comment: @RobertLongson how about "edit" link?

Comment: What about it? It's also not grayed out. Only the post contents and its comments are grayed out.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope. In normal case color is `#848D95`, for grayed is `#848DA2`.

Comment: The difference is minor, no ordinary eye can spot it, so it's meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible fix is to add link class to respective lines of [all.css](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/all.css):

- for 0.5 opacity:

  ```
  ,.downvoted-answer .comments-link
  ```
- for 1 opacity:

  ```
  ,.downvoted-answer:hover .comments-link
  ```

CSS screenshot in final:

> [image: css]

Thanks to [@Other](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/other) for an idea.